# How to switch screen with kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Hi I am trying to switch screens in kivy but it is just not working here is what I think is the necessary code:
.KV:

```
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    FileScreen:








<MainScreen>:
    name: "MainScreen"
    MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        bg_hint_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light
        data: app.data
        root_button_anim: True
        callback: app.btn

<FileScreen>:
    name: "FileScreen"
    MDBoxLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "test"
```

Python:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def switch(self):
        self.current = "FileScreen"

class FileScreen(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class app(MDApp):
    data = {
        'Create': 'file-document',
        'Open': 'folder-open'
        
    }
    def btn(self, instance):
        print('callback')
        icon = instance.icon
        # if you want check button, use
        if isinstance(instance, MDFloatingBottomButton):

            if icon == 'file-document':
                print('Create')
                MainScreen.switch(self)
                
                
            elif icon == 'folder-open':
                print('Open')
```

I really don't know what to do in this area of kivy so hopefully the community can help me out.
I am also using KivyMD if you are wondering.

Comment: This isn't really anything specific to Kivy, but a general Python mistake: you call `MainScreen.switch(self)` so `self` is your `app` class instance, so what you're actually doing is equivalent to `app.current = "FileScreen"` which obviously doesn't do anything. You need to instead call the `switch` method of the _instance_ of the `MainScreen` class that you are displaying in your gui.

Comment: How do you do this as I do not know because I am fairly new to python @inclement

Comment: This question will  be closed soon because it was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614741/why-is-switching-screens-not-working-in-kivy/68614945#68614945)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with `ScreenManager`. So you code would look like this:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class MainScreen(Screen):

    def switch_button(self):
        app.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)  #this is speed of transition between screens. if you remove this, kivy will set it to default. And you can change direction too
        app.screen_manager.current = 'FileScreen'

class FileScreen(Screen):
    pass

class app(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.mainscreen = MainScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='MainScreen')
        screen.add_widget(self.mainscreen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.filescreen = FileScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='FileScreen')
        screen.add_widget(self.filescreen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager
```

And your `kivy` code should look like this:

```
<MainScreen>:
    name: "MainScreen"
    MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        bg_hint_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light
        data: app.data
        root_button_anim: True
        callback: app.btn
        on_release: root.switch_button()

<FileScreen>:
    name: "FileScreen"
    MDBoxLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "test"
```

If you want better explanation click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbKEjD8A0ME&t=2s)

Comment: Supatashavili Its not working here is the current code: https://pastebin.com/hUkBJRph

Comment: no, just white screen. @Gurami Supatashvili