# Why is switching screens not working in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to switch screens in kivy and I have been stuck on this for a while so I don't know what is going on.
The text is being printed but the screen is still not changing.
Here is the python code if anyone can help me out:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingBottomButton



Window.size = (300, 500)

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def switch_button(self):
        print("switching")
        ScreenManager.current = "FileScreen"  
        

class FileScreen(Screen):
    pass


class app(MDApp):
    data = {
        'Create': 'file-document',
        'Open': 'folder-open'
        
    }
    def btn(self, instance):
        print('callback')
        icon = instance.icon
        # if you want check button, use
        if isinstance(instance, MDFloatingBottomButton):

            if icon == 'file-document':
                print('Create')
                MainScreen.switch_button(self)
                
                
                
            elif icon == 'folder-open':
                print('Open')

    class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
        pass

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='MainScreen'))
        sm.add_widget(FileScreen(name='FileScreen'))
        
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        #self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Teal"
        screen = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return screen
        
        

    

app().run()
```

Here is the `.KV` code:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    FileScreen:
    
<MainScreen>:
    name: "MainScreen"
    MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        bg_hint_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light
        data: app.data
        root_button_anim: True
        callback: app.btn

<FileScreen>:
    name: "FileScreen"
    MDBoxLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "test"
```

I hope the community can help me as soon as they can because if have been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are confusing classes and instances. In your `switch_button()` method your code:

```
ScreenManager.current = "FileScreen"
```

is setting the `current` attribute of the `ScreenManager` class, but the `current` property is an instance property and must be set on an instance of `ScreenManager`. And it must be the instance that is managing the `FileScreen` `Screen`.

A better coding of the `switch_button()` method:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def switch_button(self):
        print("switching")
        self.manager.current = "FileScreen"
```

The `self.manager` is a reference to the `ScreenManager` that is managing the `MainScreen`, which is also managing the `FileScreen`.

Elsewhere, you are making a similar confusion between class and instance:

```
MainScreen.switch_button(self)
```

Again, you need the instance of `MainScreen`, not the `MainScreen` class. This line can be replaced by:

```
self.root.get_screen('MainScreen').switch_button()
```

This code uses the `get_screen()` method of `ScreenManager` to access the instance of `MainScreen`, then calls the instance method `switch_button()`.

A more direct approach would be to replace that line with:

```
self.root.current = 'FileScreen'
```